# Is there any way to speed up this query capturing customer information? Is there a better method for this data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a long query but I'll try to break it down into it's parts.

First, there are the variables,

```
DECLARE @LocalCompanyCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalCompanyCode = '09'

DECLARE @LocalDivisionCode VARCHAR(5)
SET @LocalDivisionCode = '001'

DECLARE @CustomerBaseFromDate DATETIME --CustomerBase
SET @CustomerBaseFromDate = '1/1/2019'

DECLARE @CustomerBaseToDate DATETIME
SET @CustomerBaseToDate = '5/30/2019'

DECLARE @RecurringBaseFromDate DATETIME --Recurring Base
SET @RecurringBaseFromDate = '1/1/2018'

DECLARE @RecurringBaseToDate DATETIME
SET @RecurringBaseToDate = '1/1/2019'

DECLARE @LifetimeBaseFromDate DATETIME --Lifetime Base
SET @LifetimeBaseFromDate = '1/1/2015'

DECLARE @LifetimeBaseToDate DATETIME
SET @LifetimeBaseToDate = '1/1/2018'
```

Company Code and Division Code select which Company we are running this query for. Customer Base will be the base of customers that we will be looking at. So in our example, it is the past 5 months.

So for all customers in the past 5 months, we will look in our Recurring Base. This is modular so we can control what time before we consider a customer "lost". We will compare against the recurring base and see how many customers are new customers who only ordered once over the customer and recurring base, and how many customers are recurring customers, those who ordered multiple times over those periods.

Then we will also have our Lifetime base. We will check customers who ordered once or more in our lifetime base, did not order in our recurring base, but did order again in our 5 months customer base. This calculates how many customers are "Reactivated" or were considered lost but bought with us again recently.

Then I declare the four tables

```
DECLARE @FullBase TABLE
    (
        Date_Created DATE,
        Company_Code VARCHAR(2),
        Division_Code VARCHAR(3),
        Invoice_Number VARCHAR(50),
        CUST_PO VARCHAR(50),
        Total_Quantity NUMERIC,
        TotalPrice MONEY,
        City VARCHAR(50),
        State VARCHAR(50),
        Zip VARCHAR(50),
        CountryCode VARCHAR(50),
        Month NUMERIC,
        CustomerEmail VARCHAR(MAX),
        OrderCountBase NUMERIC,
        TotalOrdersBase NUMERIC
    )

DECLARE @LifetimeBase TABLE
    (
        Date_Created DATE,
        Company_Code VARCHAR(2),
        Division_Code VARCHAR(3),
        Invoice_Number VARCHAR(50),
        CUST_PO VARCHAR(50),
        Total_Quantity NUMERIC,
        TotalPrice MONEY,
        City VARCHAR(50),
        State VARCHAR(50),
        Zip VARCHAR(50),
        CountryCode VARCHAR(50),
        Month NUMERIC,
        CustomerEmail VARCHAR(MAX),
        OrderCountLifetimeBase NUMERIC,
        TotalOrdersLifetimeBase NUMERIC
    )

DECLARE @RecurringBase TABLE
    (
        Date_Created DATE,
        Company_Code VARCHAR(2),
        Division_Code VARCHAR(3),
        Invoice_Number VARCHAR(50),
        CUST_PO VARCHAR(50),
        Total_Quantity NUMERIC,
        TotalPrice MONEY,
        City VARCHAR(50),
        State VARCHAR(50),
        Zip VARCHAR(50),
        CountryCode VARCHAR(50),
        Month NUMERIC,
        CustomerEmail VARCHAR(MAX),
        OrderCountRecurringBase NUMERIC,
        TotalOrdersRecurringBase NUMERIC
    )

DECLARE @CustomerBase TABLE
    (
        Date_Created DATE,
        Company_Code VARCHAR(2),
        Division_Code VARCHAR(3),
        Invoice_Number VARCHAR(50),
        CUST_PO VARCHAR(50),
        Total_Quantity NUMERIC,
        TotalPrice MONEY,
        City VARCHAR(50),
        State VARCHAR(50),
        Zip VARCHAR(50),
        CountryCode VARCHAR(50),
        Month NUMERIC,
        CustomerEmail VARCHAR(MAX),
        OrderCountCustomerBase NUMERIC,
        TotalOrdersCustomerBase NUMERIC
    )
```

Then I insert all of our customers into the "FullBase", from the beginning of the Lifetime Base, to the end of the Customer Base

```
INSERT INTO @FullBase
        SELECT  Orders.Date_Created
                ,Orders.Company_Code
                ,Orders.Division_Code
                ,Orders.Invoice_Number
                ,Orders.CUST_PO
                ,Orders.Total_Quantity
                ,Orders.Total
                ,Orders.City
                ,Orders.State
                ,Orders.Zip
                ,Orders.CountryCode
                ,Orders.Month
                ,Orders.CustomerEmail

                ,Row_Number() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) OrderCountBase
                ,Count(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail) TotalOrdersBase

            FROM(
                Select
                    CONVERT(Date, OrderCreated) Date_Created
                    ,CONCAT ('0', LEFT(OrderName,1)) Company_Code
                    ,CONCAT ('00', RIGHT(LEFT(OrderName,2),1)) Division_Code
                    ,InvoiceNumber Invoice_Number
                    ,OrderName CUST_PO
                    ,1 Total_Quantity
                    ,TotalPrice Total
                    ,ShippingCity City
                    ,CASE WHEN ShippingCountryCode <> 'US' THEN 'INT' ELSE ShippingProvinceCode END State
                    ,ShippingZip Zip
                    ,ShippingCountryCode CountryCode
                    ,Month( OrderCreated) Month
                    ,Email CustomerEmail
                From [SHOPIFY].[shopify_moret].[dbo].orderwrappers O
                Where CONVERT(Date, O.OrderCreated) >= Convert(datetime, '05/29/2019')
                AND CONCAT ('0', LEFT(O.OrderName,1)) = @LocalCompanyCode--'09'
                AND CONCAT ('00', RIGHT(LEFT(O.OrderName,2),1)) = @LocalDivisionCode --'001'
            UNION
                Select
                    Archive.Date_Created
                    ,Archive.Company_Code
                    ,Archive.Division_Code
                    ,Archive.Invoice_Number
                    ,('91'+Archive.CUST_PO) CUST_PO
                    ,Archive.Total_Quantity
                    ,Archive.Total
                    ,Archive.City
                    ,Archive.State
                    ,Archive.Zip
                    ,Archive.Country
                    ,Archive.Month
                    ,Archive.CustomerEmail
                FROM SpraygroundArchivedOrders Archive
                Where Archive.Date_Created < Convert(datetime, '05/29/2019')
            ) Orders
            Where Orders.Date_Created BETWEEN @LifetimeBaseFromDate AND @CustomerBaseToDate
```

Here is an example of how the data looks like:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wnjVHcPHHnugywa7Qz-aqctaD4cDI5DxehNna0TyaFU/edit?usp=sharing

Then I use this full base to populate the three other tables with orders from their range.

```
INSERT INTO @LifetimeBase
    SELECT 
         F.Date_Created
        ,F.Company_Code
        ,F.Division_Code
        ,F.Invoice_Number
        ,F.CUST_PO
        ,F.Total_Quantity
        ,F.TotalPrice
        ,F.City
        ,F.State
        ,F.Zip
        ,F.CountryCode
        ,F.Month
        ,F.CustomerEmail
        ,Row_Number() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) OrderCountLifetimeBase
        ,Count(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail) TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
    FROM @FullBase F
    Where F.Date_Created BETWEEN @LifetimeBaseFromDate AND @LifetimeBaseToDate 

    INSERT INTO @RecurringBase
    SELECT 
         F.Date_Created
        ,F.Company_Code
        ,F.Division_Code
        ,F.Invoice_Number
        ,F.CUST_PO
        ,F.Total_Quantity
        ,F.TotalPrice
        ,F.City
        ,F.State
        ,F.Zip
        ,F.CountryCode
        ,F.Month
        ,F.CustomerEmail
        ,Row_Number() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) OrderCountRecurringBase
        ,Count(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail) TotalOrdersRecurringBase
    FROM @FullBase F
    Where F.Date_Created BETWEEN @RecurringBaseFromDate AND @RecurringBaseToDate 

    INSERT INTO @CustomerBase
    SELECT 
         F.Date_Created
        ,F.Company_Code
        ,F.Division_Code
        ,F.Invoice_Number
        ,F.CUST_PO
        ,F.Total_Quantity
        ,F.TotalPrice
        ,F.City
        ,F.State
        ,F.Zip
        ,F.CountryCode
        ,F.Month
        ,F.CustomerEmail
        ,Row_Number() over (partition by CustomerEmail order by Date_Created asc) OrderCountCustomerBase
        ,Count(*) over (partition by CustomerEmail) TotalOrdersCustomerBase
    FROM @FullBase F
    Where F.Date_Created BETWEEN @CustomerBaseFromDate AND @CustomerBaseToDate
```

If I just select * from an of the bases, including the full base, the query only takes a few seconds to run and returns 140,000 rows (for the @FullBase) of all customer orders.

However, the final part of this query, which is the part that runs, takes 10 minutes to run for my 6 months of customers

```
SELECT 
    CC.CustomerEmail
    ,CC.TotalOrdersCustomerBase
    ,RC.TotalOrdersRecurringBase
    ,LC.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
    From
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        C.CustomerEmail
        ,C.TotalOrdersCustomerBase
        FROM
        @CustomerBase C
    ) CC
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        R.CustomerEmail
        ,R.TotalOrdersRecurringBase
        FROM
        @RecurringBase R
    ) RC ON CC.CustomerEmail = RC.CustomerEmail

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        L.CustomerEmail
        ,L.TotalOrdersLifetimeBase
        FROM
        @LifetimeBase L
    ) LC ON CC.CustomerEmail = LC.CustomerEmail
```

Does anyone have any tips for me at all? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You need temporary tables and indexes on the joining columns! Try to also avoid DISTINCT.

Comment: Rather than provide a link to a Google doc for your data include it in your question, preferable as a DML (`INSERT`) statement. Volunteers are unlikely to be happy being forced to use an off-site resource to be able to help you.

Comment: @EzLo I am using Table Variables, I read they were faster than temporary tables. Can you tell me more about how to add indexes to my temporary tables.

Comment: Table variables can be faster, but not always. As with everything in sql server, it depends. Cardinality estimates always assume just one row which can result in pretty horrible execution plans when there are lots of rows. As for adding indexes to a temp table...just like a persistent table. [Here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/indexing-temp-tables/) is an awesome article on the topic.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually, changing the table from table variable to temporary tables almost fixed the issue entirely without even doing anything with indexes! However, if I try to run the query multiple times in a row, I get the "There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database."  How do I fix this? Do I just drop all my temporary tables at the start of the query?

Comment: Why do you need to drop a temp table and then populate it again? Populate the temp tables ONE TIME in your code, then you can query them as many times as you need.

Comment: I am only populating them once. For each temp table I do something like this. SELECT ...
 INTO #CustomerBase
 FROM #FullBase F
 Where F.Date_Created BETWEEN CustomerBaseFromDate AND CustomerBaseToDate.  I don't declare the table, I don't define it, anything. Just use the keyword INTO with the first appearance of the table name.

Comment: if a temp table is "already existing" then you are not running this as a proc or you are not "exec" executing the procedure. you are likely testing this and running a batch in a single query window? The first time you run, it creates the tables. Since your connection/batch is still open, the temp tables remain. That wont be the case when run in a proc

Comment: @jamie you are correct and I understand. Thanks!